# C# graphics рисование на picturebox

Tags: javascript, c#, графика

Как правильно организовать аналог requestAnimationFrame (из js) в c# win forms? Как использовать больше ресурсов, чтобы ускорить отрисовку? Хотелось бы услышать что-нибудь про двойной буфер.

```
 public Form1()
 {
        InitializeComponent();
        bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
        gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
 }
 //....
 //много разных обработчиков событий, которые изменяют Points и перерисовывают, вызвав reDraw()
 //....
 private void reDraw()
 {
        gr.Clear(backgroundColor);
        //....
        //много раз вызываю функции, которые рисуют различные фигуры по точкам Points
        //типа gr.DrawLine() gr.DrawArc()....
        //....
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        gr.Dispose();
 }
```

Comment: А как вы сейчас рисуете? Приведите фрагмент кода, который у вас рисует медленно. Тут одно из двух, либо дам ссылку на ответ, который уже писал тут ранее, либо помогу исправить текущий. Но без вашего кода сложно понять что именно у вас не получается. GDI+ конечно довольно медленный, если сравнивать с DirectX или OpenGL, которые используют ресурсы видеокарты на полную, но не на столько, чтобы не осилить элементарную анимацию.

Comment: static double[,] Points = new double[8, 3] { {...} };
static Graphics gr;
static Bitmap bmp;
в пространстве имен

Comment: Понятно... как я и думал, вы рисуете в онлайне, поэтому и долго. Попробуйте взять два битмапа и поочередно - на одном рисуем другой показываем. Рисование картинки целиком значительно быстрее чем формирование из примитивов.

Comment: @rdorn не совсем понял. Где объявить второй битмап? И в каком месте показывать первый/второй?

Comment: Прямо в форме заведите дополнительное поле для текущего рисуемого кадра, и меняйте его местами с изображением в PictuBox через локальную переменную, когда новый кадр отрисован полностью. Чуть позже напишу небольшой пример.

Comment: @rdorn а намного ли сложнее использовать аппаратное ускорение?

Comment: Что-то я не смог так нагрузить GDI, чтобы увидеть значительные артефакты. Может какой-нибудь пример приведете для демонстрации проблемы, добавьте в вопрос? Я конечно могу предположить, что текущий конфиг домашнего компа просто не замечает подобную нагрузку, но все таки. А по поводу аппаратного ускорения - смотря с чем сравнивать, посмотрите примеры работы с любой .net-оберткой для OpenGL или DirectX

Comment: @rdorn а можно пример кода, directX или openGL, где изображается отрезок на форме?

Comment: [тут](http://esate.ru/uroki/OpenGL/uroki-OpenGL-c-sharp/) можно почитать и посмотреть примеры, оно немного устарело, TAO успел превратиться в OpenTK, но общий принцип понятен, с небольшими поправками на актуальную документацию.

Comment: @rdorn никак не могу понять... Код аналогичный? Есть что-нибудь подобное Graphics.DrawLine()? Я там смотрю? http://esate.ru/uroki/OpenGL/uroki-OpenGL-c-sharp/chto-takoe-opengl/

Comment: там отдельно про 2д примитивы урок. И нет, аналогичных конструкций не будет, все на векторах